# VBA Excel Alternative for Locked property?

Tags: vba, excel

Will you please tell me an alternative for **Locked** property.

Actually I have some macros, with those macros I am locking some cells and unlocking the same cells based on userEnvironments, but the client wants it as a sharedworkbook so that multiple users can edit at a time. Locking requires **Unprotect** and **Protect** which is not possible when the workbook is **shared**.

Offo! So will you please give me an alternative for my problem.
Any help would be appreciated greatly.

Comment: Is the Locked property still available? (even if you cant protect the sheet to enable the locking)

Comment: I do not believe that it is possible to have multiple people editing the same Excel workbook.  Not successfully anyway. Inevitably, someone will lose their edits. This is what a database is for.

Comment: Excel 2010(+) does have the ability to share workbooks, not sure about multiple users at the same time, but it (apparantly) has conflict resolution type stuff - http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/about-shared-workbooks-HP005262294.aspx

Comment: @NickSlash multiple users at the same time still works pretty well. The users can manipulate the workbook as they see fit, and are notified of a conflict if one arises. The user then has the choice to overwrite with his/her own changes or leave the other users changes unedited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

```
Dim cell As Range 
Dim Rng As Range 
Dim Flag As Boolean 

Flag = False 

For Each Rng In Target.Cells 

    For Each cell In Worksheets("DATA").Range("A1:AZ10") 
        If cell.Address = Rng.Address Then 
            MsgBox "You are not authorized to edit cells in this range." 
            Application.EnableEvents = False 
            Application.Undo 
            Application.EnableEvents = True 
            Flag = True 
            Exit For 
        End If 
    Next cell 

    If Flag = True Then 
        Exit For 
    End If 

Next Rng
```

End Sub

Atlast i got answer for my question..

Comment: You could replace the loop with 'If Not Intersect(Worksheets("DATA").Range("A1:AZ10"), Target) is Nothing Then' saves you looping over the whole range.

Comment: @NickSlash,Thanks for your response:-)

Comment: @NickSlash, your if conditional statement is working like a charm by avoiding loops and time complexity. thank you soo much:-)

Answer (score 0):

If the locked property is still available, then you can make it not possible to select locked cells. This wont stop a determined user, since they could just disable the macro, but I guess the locking is more to stop accidental edits to formulas and stuff?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim Cr As Range
Dim Rr As Range
If Not Target.Rows.Count > 1 And Not Target.Columns.Count > 1 Then
    If Target.Locked = True Then
        Target.Offset(ColumnOffset:=1).Select
    End If
Else
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1000 Then
        Debug.Print "Selection too big!"
        Target.Cells(1,1).Select
        Exit Sub
    End If
    For Each Cr In Target.Cells
        If Cr.Locked = False Then
            If Rr Is Nothing Then
                Set Rr = Cr
            Else
                Set Rr = Application.Union(Rr, Cr)
            End If
        End If
    Next Cr
    If Not Rr Is Nothing Then
        Rr.Select
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

When a user selects a single cell and its locked property is true it moves them right to the next unlocked column. If its a selected area, it removes all locked cells from the area. I've not really tested it much, and its probably not the best solution :)